# Extending a class in PHP

Tags: php, class, extend

```
class A{
  private static $instance;

  public static function getInstance(){

    if(!(self::$instance instanceof self))
      self::$instance = new self();

    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function doStuff(){
    echo 'stuff';
  }


}

class B extends A{
  public function doStuff(){
    echo 'other stuff';
  }
}

A::getInstance()->doStuff(); // prints "stuff"

B::getInstance()->doStuff(); // prints "stuff" instead of 'other stuff';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Why doesn't class B run it's function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the code in `getInstance`:

```
 if(!(self::$instance instanceof self))
       self::$instance = new self();
```

All those `self`s point to `A`, not to the class that was called.  PHP 5.3 introduces something called ["late static binding"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), which allows you to point to the class that was called, not to the class where the code exists.  You need to use the `static` keyword:

```
class A{
  protected static $instance;  // converted to protected so B can inherit

  public static function getInstance(){
    if(!(static::$instance instanceof static))
      static::$instance = new static(); // use B::$instance to store an instance of B

    return static::$instance;
  }

  public function doStuff(){
    echo 'stuff';
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this will fail if you don't have PHP 5.3 at least.

Answer (score 4):

Because you've used self in getInstance of  class A, when you call getInstance in class B, I believe self is still refering to class A... if that makes any sense.

So basically, you're calling doStuff() on 2 instances of A.

Answer (score 2):

This is because PHP (in the version you're using) binds static functions to the class they were defined in.

So `B::getInstance()` returns an object of class A.

I believe this has been changed in PHP 5.3+, as it was a source of great pain to many (myself included!).

Some details on this are up at:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code for getInstance()

```
public static function getInstance(){

    if(!self::$instance)
    {
      $curClass = get_called_class();
      self::$instance = new $curClass();
    }

    return self::$instance;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

self:: is still in class A, no matter what you call it with